# gas powervent water heater replacement

Tags: plumbing

I need to replace my old Rheem PoverVent 50 gallons gas water heater, can't afford a similar replacement. Can I replace it with a non-power vent water heater? It the same size and spec.

Comment: Usually no. A power-vent is normally employed when there is inadequate rise in the vent pipe to create adequate draft.

Comment: ...but may also be used for greater efficiency, and if it replaced a normally vented heater, there may be a vent in place you can use.

Comment: Can you provide us with information about how the venting's set up? Is there a reason you want to use a non-power-vent heater, for that matter?

Comment: Can you provide photos of the existing vent? Is it straight up or are there bends, going into wall spaces some plans specify power vent, straight shot single story a standard vented model may work.